# How to output the element in list with the unique id using Thymeleaf in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my entity class, I have a arraylist that have stored a list of enrolled student. Whenever I click the **student** button, it will show a enrolled student list. The [below screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hoBz.png) is my enroll student page. But when I click on the other button to show their own enrolled student list, it show the [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V42GW.png) for the first row. It supposed to be unique record for each id.

For my attempt I have tried to write the `@requestMapping` that is to retrieve only one id. So   when I click on the student button, it will only return the enrolled student list of corresponding row. But it failed, so how should I do now to get the unique record for each row?

[image]

```
public class Exam {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "duration", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private double duration;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="exam_enrolled_student",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    private List<User> enrolledStudent = new ArrayList<User>();
```

**Controller method to get a single id**

```
@RequestMapping("/getOneExamSchedule")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Exam> getOneExamSchedule(Long id){
        return examService.getOneExam(id);
    }
```

**Below is the code for the *student button* and the modal to show the enrolled student list.**

```
<tbody>
                        <tr th:each="exam: ${listExam}">
                            
                                
                            <td><a th:href="@{/getOneExamSchedule/(id=${exam.id})}" type="button" id="studentListDetailBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#studentListModal">Student
                                    <span class="badge badge-light" th:text="${#lists.size(exam.enrolledStudent)}">[Number of elements]</span>
                                </a> 
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="studentListModal"
                                    data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
                                    aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Enrolled
                                                    Student List</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                    aria-label="Close"></button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <ol th:each = "student:${exam.enrolledStudent}" class="list-group list">
                                                    <li
                                                        class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
                                                        <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                                                            <div id="studentName" th:text="|Student Name: ${student.username}|" class="fw-bold" >Student Name</div>
                                                            <ol class="list-group list ms-4">
                                                                <li id="studentEmail" th:text="|Email : ${student.email}|"></li>
                                                                <li id ="studentEduInst" th:text="|Educational Instituion : ${student.eduInst}"|></li>
                                                            </ol>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    
                                                </ol>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: I’m away from my computer so I can’t say for sure, but I do see that your modal calls `exam.enrolledStudent`, which would be fine if `getOneExamSchedule` returns an ` Exam ` - but it doesn’t, it returns an ` Optional `, so I’d try making it something like `exam.get().enrolledStudent`

Comment: I try what u suggest, it trigger the error. If use ```exam.get().enrolledStudent```, it cant access the enrolled student list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate this modal `<div>` for each element in `listExam`, all using the same `studentListModal` id. Each of those modals should have a unique id.

Replace:

`id="studentListModal"`

with:

`th:id="|studentListModal-${exam.id}|"`

on the modal itself.

Also update the trigger on the button:

`data-target="#studentListModal"`

should be:

`th:attr="data-target=|#studentListModal-${exam.id}|"`

(Not 100% sure of that last one, check the generated HTML in your browser to make sure it matches with the id's of the modals).

Finally, do not return `Optional` from a controller method. I suggest to use:

```
@RequestMapping("/getOneExamSchedule")
    @ResponseBody
    public Exam getOneExamSchedule(Long id){
        return examService.getOneExam(id)
               orElseThrow( () -> new ExamNotFoundException(id));
    }
```

(Where `ExamNotFoundException` is an exception class you create for your application).

Comment: I don't even know how to thank you. I've been searching for the solution the whole day and yours solved it in a minute. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have one doubt that want to clarify with u. Why need use the throw exception instead of the Optional? Is there any reason?

Comment: What you return there is converted to JSON. How should an `Optional` of something look like in JSON? It is better to return the actual object.